# How to log into the ban section of discord using discord.js v12?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm working on my ban command and it's fully functional, but I was wondering, how I would log the ban reason into the ban section of discord (example in the attachment)? My code looks like this:

```
const { DiscordAPIError } = require("discord.js");
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: "Mentioned user will be banned",
    execute(message, args){
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("Invalid Permissions")
        let User = message.guild.member(message.mentions.members.first()) || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
        if (!User) return message.channel.send("Invalid User")
        if (User.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.reply("Invalid Permissions a")
        let banReason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
        if (!banReason) {
            banReason = "None"
        }
        console.log(`USER = ${User}`)
        User.ban
        console.log(`Ban reason = ${banReason}`)
        var UserID = User.id
        console.log(`USER ID = ${UserID}`)
    }
}
```

Any help? Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite easy, just add `({reason: banReason})` after the `User.ban` part, making it:

```
User.ban({reason: banReason})
```

That should log it there properly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reason` property of the `options` parameter in the [`GuildMember.ban()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban) method:

```js
User.ban({ reason: 'real life danger' })
  .then(member => console.log(`${member.name} was banned.`))
  .catch(console.error)
```

---

Also, in your code, there's no reason for using the `Guild.member()` method when defining `User`. `Guild.member(user)` is used to turn a `User` object into a `GuildMember` object.

However, [`MessageMentions.members.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) *already* returns a `GuildMember` object, making it obsolete.